# Why is there no Google Cloud project available to add Firebase services?

Tags: firebase, error-handling, terminal, command-line

When I run the `firebase init` command, I get an error.

Here is the terminal:

```
     ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########
     ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##
     ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######
     ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##
     ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  /Users/name/development/projects/python/project-id

? Which Firebase features do you want to set up for this directory? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices. Firestore
: Configure security rules and indexes files for Firestore

=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

? Please select an option: Add Firebase to an existing Google Cloud Platform project

Error: There are no available Google Cloud projects to add Firebase services.
```

I really don't understand this error very well, why does this error occur?

I didn't include the code because I don't think the error has anything to do with the code.

How can I fix this error? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you do `firebase login`?

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec, I did it